# How do people get away with old TV clips in music?

Tags: copyright, music

For example, old news coverage from decades ago (landing on the moon, things like that).  Presumably there are copyright laws but such clips may be in songs, including clips of well known anchors talking.  Is there a legal loophole for this or are people just sometimes avoiding getting caught?

Comment: There's another option you didn't mention, they may be paying royalties.

Comment: It's not a legal loophole; it's the fair-use exception to copyright law.

Comment: For the actual clip of the moon landing itself, that was the product of a US government agency, and is thus in the public domain.